# extern for a new defined struct in C

Tags: c, compilation, extern

I have main in which I used the node struct however defintion of node and it's manipulation operations are localed in a file in the directory called NODE/

I created NODE/node.h which has:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
        int my_reg;
        node *left;
        node *right;
} ;
```

I created NODE/node.c and include in it node.h which has node_insert node_remove;

However I am using the node struction in school_address.c in which I also include NODE/node.h and NODE/node.c

I tried putting

`extern struct node`

in school_address.c

Yet the code doesn't compile and complains of redefinition in node.h

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you show the code that actually produces the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` is for variables, not type definitions. You should just include the header in all modules that need to know about `struct node`; that is substituted for the entire header's content, inline.

What you should **not** do is include a C file in another C file. Instead, you should declare the prototypes of the common functions in a header.

E.g.,

```
#include "node.h"

int main()
{
    // whatever
}
```

becomes, if you put the prototype for `node_insert` in the header,

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
        int my_reg;
        node *left;
        node *right;
};

struct node *node_insert(struct node *, int);  // or whatever the prototype is

int main()
{
    // whatever
}
```

after the C preprocessor is done with it, so `struct node` and `node_insert` are visible in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an [Include Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Specifically, use

```
#ifndef node_h_
#define node_h_ 1
```

at the beginning of node.h, and the corresponding

```
#endif
```

at the end of it.

Also, do not include `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

When your header files are included by multiple C files you have to include them in preprocessor directives to avoid double definitions, such as:

```
#ifndef __NODE_H_INCLUDED__
#define __NODE_H_INCLUDED__

struct node...

#endif
```

It's good practice to do this anyway in all your header files.